# JFrame Scroll bar and Canvas

Tags: java, canvas, jframe, scrollbar

I'm having trouble trying to add a horizontal scroll bar to a JFrame that has a canvas. I draw an images onto the canvas and sometimes these images over-run the screen so I want a scroll bar to enable the user to see them.

Here is the key section in the code, if any other code is needed please let me know and i'll edit.

Could anyone point out what i'm doing wrong ?

Many Thanks J

```
public class TheFrame extends JFrame {

private static ThePanel canvas;
private String deckImagesToUse;

/**
 * The constructor creates a Frame ready to display the cards
 */
public TheFrame(String cardImgFile) {


    // Calls the constructor in the JFrame superclass passing up the name to 
    // display in the title
    super("Window title");

    //Using users choice of cards
    deckImagesToUse = cardImgFile;

    // When you click on the close window button the window will be closed
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // This has North, East, South, West and center positions for components
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    // This is what we will draw on (see the inner class below)
    canvas = new ThePanel();
    setSize(700, 300);
    this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //Scroll Bar
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(canvas);
    //scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    this.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    int desiredWidth = (Pack.cardsInPlay.size() * 70);
    Dimension d = new Dimension(desiredWidth,300);
    canvas.setPreferredSize(d);

    setVisible(true); // Display the window


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
canvas = new ThePanel();
setSize(700, 300);
this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The setting size and adding to `this` is futile because later scrollpane ignores it.

When your image is bigger than the `JScrollPane` just call `canvas.setPreferredSize(imageWidth, imageHeight);`